# word tokenization in python

Tags: python, text, nltk, tokenize

I am new to Python and text analytics, i wanted to tokenize my text corpus:

```
<s> c a b c b c </s>
<s> a c b a </s>
<s> c a c a c </s>

I wanted to tokenize them into ['<s>','c','a','b','c','</s>'], but what i got is:
['<', 's', '>', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', '<', '/s', '>']
```

the "s" and "/s" is seperated with <,> as a different token. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
import nltk
#read file
f = open('Text Corpus.txt','r')
corpus = f.read()
print (corpus)

#tokenize
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(corpus)
print(tokens)
```

Comment: You should open the file “rt” - and for what you seem to want simply `f.split()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like markup. You can use `BeautifulSoup` to remove it.

```
import nltk

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

corpus = """
<s> c a b c b c </s>
<s> a c b a </s>
<s> c a c a c </s>
"""

print(nltk.word_tokenize(BeautifulSoup(corpus, "html.parser").get_text()))
```

Output:

```
['c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c']
```

If, however, you want to keep the tags, just do this:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    corpus = f.read().split()

print(corpus)
```

`sample.txt` holds the corpus example you gave.

Output:

```
['<s>', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>', '<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', '</s>', '<s>', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', '</s>']
```